# Google Classroom test account password reset

Tags: google-classroom

I forgot the password on my test teacher account for Google Classroom. Is there any way to get it reset? The normal login "forgot password" doesn't help since it will send the password to the test account (which I don't have access to). I could not find any place on the Google Classroom web site to ask for help nor can I simply get another account.

Comment: Your best bet is probably just to fill out the form again and get a new test account.

Comment: The form does not allow you to fill it out more than once. However, I can use a different e-mail address to get around that, which is what I've ended up doing.